# how to access text file from s3 bucket into sagemaker for training a model?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train chatbot model using tensorflow and seq to seq architecture using sagemaker also I have completed coding in spyder but when 
I am trying to access cornel movie corpus dataset from s3 bucket into sagemaker it says no such file or directory even granting access to s3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

- if you're in a **notebook**: `aws s3 cp s3://path_to_the_file /home/ec2-user/SageMaker` will copy data from s3 to your SageMaker directory in the notebook (if you have the IAM permissions to do so)
- if you're in the **docker container of a SageMaker training job**: you need to pass the s3 path to the SDK training call: `estimator.fit({'mydata':'s3://path_to_the_file'})` and in the docker your tensorflow code must read from this path: `opt/ml/input/data/mydata`